# new or new[] operator

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

Consider following code:

```
typedef  SomeType type_t[2];
SomeType * arr1 = new type_t; //new or new[] ???
type_t * arr2 = new type_t[3]; //new or new[] ???
```

According standard which version of `new` will be called in 1-st and 2-nd cases ( `new` or `new[]`) and how to delete `arr1` and `arr2` (with `delete` or `delete[]`) ?

Comment: To be honest this is probably bad practice

Comment: This is definitely bad practice, and would likely cause someone a headache down the road.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First case allocates a one-dimensional array, second case a two-dimensional array. Both of them must be released via `delete[]`, otherwise you will get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It will use `new[]` in both cases. You can verify this yourself by defining `operator new[]` for `SomeType` and printing something to the screen. You will see that it will be printed in both cases.